# Prove the irrationality of $0.100\, 000\, 000\, 100\ldots$ with $1$s at every power of $10$ index

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

So $x = 0.a_1a_2a_3...a_na_{n+1}a_{n+2}...$
$a_n = 1$ if $n = 10^k$ $k\in\mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$
$a_n = 0$ if $n \neq 10^k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$

It's obvious that $x$ is not rational since it doesn't have period, because for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$10^n - 10^{n-1} \neq 10^{n-1} - 10^{n-2}$
This means that number of zeros between "1"s is always different.
$x$ would be rational though if
$\forall l\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$
$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$
$\exists m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\{a_N,a_{N+1},\cdots ,a_{N+m}\}=\{a_{N+lm},a_{N+lm+1},\cdots a_{N+lm+m}\}$$
So I described what this sequence looks like, but I have no clue, what to do next. My intuition says that irrationality of $x$ should be proved using "contradiction method", which implies assumption, that $x$ is rational, hence it has period, therefore some sequence of $a$s is not a subset of an another larger sequence of $a$s with different indexes. But how to prove it and how to write it mathematically is unfortunately unclear.

Comment: This seems to be a Liouville number and therefore transcendental, but I have not much experience with proofs of numbers to be a Liouville number.

Comment: The irrationality follows from the fact that we have arbitary long chains of zeros and infinite many ones in the decimal expansion. This is impossible for a rational number.

Comment: The criterion for rationality in base 10 is: eventually periodic.  So show this one is not eventually periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [@Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter), it is sufficient to show that the amount of $0$s between the $1$s goes to infinity. Specifically, as there are $10^k-1$ digits before the $k$th $1$, there are $10^k-10^{k-1}-1$ $0$s between the $(k-1)$st and $k$th $1$, and this amount goes to infinity.

Additionally, while not necessarily Liouville, this number can be shown to have [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) $\mu\ge 10$, which implies that the number is transcendental, as all irrational algebraic numbers have irrationality measure $\mu=2$.

In order to prove $\mu\ge 10$, where $\mu$ is defined as the largest value such that $0<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^\mu}$ is satisfied for infinitely many coprime $(p,q)$ first note that $x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{10^{-10^k}}$, and then define the integer sequences $q_n=10^{10^n}$ and $p_n=q_n\sum_{k=0}^n{10^{-10^k}}$, which works as $q_n$ divides every $q_k$ for $k\le n$. Then substitute and simplify:

$0<\left|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|=\left|x-\frac{q_n\sum_{k=0}^n{10^{-10^k}}}{q_n}\right|=\left|x-\sum_{k=0}^n{10^{-10^k}}\right|=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty{10^{-10^k}}<2*10^{-10^{n+1}}=2*(10^{-10^n})^{10}=(10^{-10^n})^{10-\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{q_n^{10-\varepsilon}}$

Here, $\varepsilon=10-\frac{10^{n+1}\log(10)}{10^n\log(10)+\log(2)}$ which approaches $0$, so there are ininitely many coprime integer pairs $(p_n,q_n)$ for which $0<\left|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\frac{1}{q_n^{10-\varepsilon}}$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and so $\mu\ge 10$. Conveniently, as the unique prime factors of $q_n$ are exactly $\{2,5\}$, and $p_n=1+\sum_{k=0}{10^{10^n-10^k}}$, where the whole sum is divisible by $2$ and $5$, it follows that $p_n$ and $q_n$ are coprime. This proof is very similar to the one given on the Wikipedia page for [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), though with a few important differences.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A:=\{10^k:k\in\Bbb N\}$, and $A\!\restriction \!n:=A\cap\{1,...,n\}$. We are asked to prove that $\sum_{n\in A}10^{-n}$ is irrational. To do so, suppose otherwise. Thus, let
$$\sum_{n\in A}10^{-n}=\frac pq,$$
where $p\in\Bbb N$ and $q\in \Bbb Z_+$. Let $$m:=\min\{n\in A:q<10^{9n-1}\}.$$ We have
$$10^mp=q\sum_{n\in A}10^{m-n}=q\sum_{n\in A\restriction m}10^{m-n}+q\sum_{n\in A\setminus  A\restriction m}10^{m-n}.$$
Now the first term on the RHS above is an integer, and so the second is too:
$$q\sum_{n\in A\setminus  A\restriction m}10^{m-n}\in \Bbb N.$$
The value of $n$ in the initial term in the above sum is $10m$, and so the statement may be written as
$$10^{-9m}q\left(1+\sum_{n\in A\setminus  A\restriction 10m}10^{10m-n}\right)\in \Bbb N.$$Since the parenthetic factor above is less than $2$, we have a contradiction by the choice of $m$.